# Why my Chrome Console is showing this message

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Av0u.png)

I want why this is shown, is there any issue with my machine?

Comment: It's there because the developer put it there as a warning to you. Nothing is wrong with your machine.

Comment: This sounds off-topic for this site. Please kindly read [this Help Center page](/help/on-topic) to learn what's on-topic here. See also: ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask) If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on [meta.se] using the \[site-recommendation\] tag.

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The site put the message to avoid someone fools an user to use scripts in the page.
You can do it in yourself with:

```
console.warn('Message')
```